# How to get json data without api

Tags: php, python-requests, posts

I'm trying to get the viewer count so I can check if a streamer is online on https://www.dlive.tv/. If you view the page source on a streamer's page (https://www.dlive.tv/thelongestchain), there's a bunch of json and "watchingCount" is there.

Basically, I want to have the streamer appear on the "Live Now" section of my site if their viewer count is 1 or more, but I can't figure out anyway on how to get the viewer count. I know I could use something like Selenium if I was using python and could run it from my pc, but I need the site to know it.

DLive doesn't have an api yet, so I don't know how to make a call(or request I don't know the terminology) to get this info. When I look in the network tab on chrome I see that there's a call (https://graphigo.prd.dlive.tv/) that provides stream info I think. Would I also need my authkey?

I realize this question is broad and all over the place but it's because so am I with me trying to solve this the last couple days. If I had the viewercount as a variable, I know how to display the streamer on the "Live Now" section of my site, I just don't know how to get the necessary data.

If there's another way I should be checking if a streamer is online or offline other than getting the viewercount, that would work too. If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it, thanks.

I tried scraping the page but I don't think you can scrape dynamic content. When I tried to use SimpleHTMLDom it just returned static elements.

```php
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://www.dlive.tv/thelongestchain')

if(($html->find('video', 0))) { 
    echo 'online';
}else{
    echo 'offline';
}

/* The video element is only on the page if the streamer is live, but it doesn't return because it's not static I presume */

?>
```

I have no idea at all how to go about making a call/request to get the json data for the viewer count, or how to get any other data that could check if a streamer is online. All the scraping I've done did not return any elements that weren't static (the same no matter if the streamer was online or offline).

Comment: Your code above may work if you instead called it from JS so you could constantly query the page for this element.

Comment: @prieber How would I call it from JS?

Comment: I was thinking something like `$.get('http://example.com/your-script.php', function...)` but I don't believe that will solve the dynamic content problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try cURL, it's like a magic wand.

This will return the entire page, and I think including the JSON you're looking for:

```
<?php

        $curl = curl_init('https://www.dlive.tv/thelongestchain'); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        var_dump($result); // you do as you need to here
        curl_close($curl);   

?>
```

Here's the `<script>` containing the data I believe you need. Assuming "watchingCount" is the same thing you're looking for?

```
<script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__={"version":"1.2.0","snackbar":{"snackbar":null},"accessToken":{"accessToken":null},"userMeta":{"userMeta":{"fingerprint":null,"referrer":{"isFirstTime":true,"streamer":null,"happyHour":null,"user":null},"ipStats":null,"ip":"34.216.252.62","langCode":"en","trackingInfo":{"rank":"not available","prevPage":"not available","postStatus":"not available"},"darkMode":true,"NSFW":false,"prefetchID":"e278e744-f522-480e-a290-8eed0fe83b07","cashinEmail":""}},"me":{"me":null},"dialog":{"dialog":{"login":false,"subscribe":false,"cashIn":false,"chest":false,"chestWinners":false,"downloadApp":false}},"tabs":{"tabs":{"livestreamMobileActiveTab":"tab-chat"}},"globalInfo":{"globalInfo":{"languages":[],"communityUpdates":[],"recommendChannels":[]}},"ui":{"ui":{"viewPointWidth":1920,"mq":4,"isMobile":false}}};(function(){var s;(s=document.currentScript||document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1]).parentNode.removeChild(s);}());</script> <script>window.__APOLLO_STATE__={"defaultClient":{"user:dlive-00431789":{"id":"user:dlive-00431789","avatar":"https:\u002F\u002Fimages.prd.dlivecdn.com\u002Favatar\u002F5c1330d8-5bc8-11e9-ab17-865634f95b6b","__typename":"User","displayname":"thelongestchain","partnerStatus":"NONE","username":"dlive-00431789","canSubscribe":false,"subSetting":null,"followers":{"type":"id","generated":true,"id":"$user:dlive-00431789.followers","typename":"UserConnection"},"livestream":{"type":"id","generated":false,"id":"livestream:dlive-00431789+i7rCywMWg","typename":"Livestream"},"hostingLivestream":null,"offlineImage":"https:\u002F\u002Fimages.prd.dlivecdn.com\u002Fofflineimage\u002Fvideo-placeholder.png","banStatus":"NO_BAN","deactivated":false,"about":"#lovejonah\n\nJonah's NEW FRIENDS:\nhttps:\u002F\u002Fdlive.tv\u002FFlamenco https:\u002F\u002Fi.gyazo.com\u002F88416fca5047381105da289faba60e7c.png\nhttps:\u002F\u002Fdlive.tv\u002FHamsterSamster https:\u002F\u002Fi.gyazo.com\u002F984b19f77a1de5e3028e42ccd71052a0.png\nhttps:\u002F\u002Fdlive.tv\u002Fjayis4justice \nhttps:\u002F\u002Fdlive.tv\u002FDenomic\nhttps:\u002F\u002Fdlive.tv\u002FCutie\nhttps:\u002F\u002Fdlive.tv\u002FTruly_A_No_Life\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nOur Socials:\nhttps:\u002F\u002Fwww.twitch.tv\u002Fthelongestchain\nhttps:\u002F\u002Fdiscord.gg\u002Fsagd68Z\n\nLINO website: https:\u002F\u002Flino.network\nLINO Whitepaper: https:\u002F\u002Fdocsend.com\u002Fview\u002Fy9qtwb6\nLINO Tracker :  https:\u002F\u002Ftracker.lino.network\u002F#\u002F\nLINO Discord : https:\u002F\u002Fdiscord.gg\u002FTUxp3ww\n\nThe Legend of Lemon's: https:\u002F\u002Fbubbl.us\u002FNTE1OTA4MS85ODY3ODQwL2M0Y2NjNjRlYmI0ZGNkNDllOTljNDMxODExNjFmZDRk-X?utm_source=shared-link&utm_medium=link&s=9867840\n\nPC:\nAMD FX 6core 3.0ghz ddr3\n12GB RAM HyperFury X Blue ddr3\nCooler Master Hyper 6heatpipe cpu cooler\nGigabyte MB\n2 x EVGA 1070 FTW\nKingston SSD 120gb\nKingston SSD 240GB\nREDDRAGON Keyboard\nREDDRAGON Mouse\nBlack Out Blue Yeti Microphone\nLogitech C922\n\nApps Used:\nBig Trades Tracker: https:\u002F\u002Ftucsky.github.io\u002FSignificantTrades\u002F#\nMultiple Charts: \nhttps:\u002F\u002Fcryptotrading.toys\u002Fcrypto-panel\u002F\nhttps:\u002F\u002Fcryptowatch.net\n\n\n\n","treasureChest":{"type":"id","generated":true,"id":"$user:dlive-00431789.treasureChest","typename":"TreasureChest"},"videos":{"type":"id","generated":true,"id":"$user:dlive-00431789.videos","typename":"VideoConnection"},"pastBroadcasts":{"type":"id","generated":true,"id":"$user:dlive-00431789.pastBroadcasts","typename":"PastBroadcastConnection"},"following":{"type":"id","generated":true,"id":"$user:dlive-00431789.following","typename":"UserConnection"}},"$user:dlive-00431789.followers":{"totalCount":1000,"__typename":"UserConnection"},"livestream:dlive-00431789+i7rCywMWg":{"id":"livestream:dlive-00431789+i7rCywMWg","totalReward":"3243600","watchingCount":5,"permlink":"dlive-00431789+i7rCywMWg","title":"bybit 0.1eth HIGH LEVERAGE","content":"","category":{"type":"id","generated":false,"id":"category:11455","typename":"Category"},"creator":{"type":"id","generated":false,"id":"user:dlive-00431789","typename":"User"},"__typename":"Livestream","language":{"type":"id","generated":false,"id":"language:1","typename":"Language"},"watchTime({\"add\":false})":true,"disableAlert":false},"category:11455":{"id":"category:11455","backendID":11455,"title":"Cryptocurrency","__typename":"Category","imgUrl":"https:\u002F\u002Fimages.prd.dlivecdn.com\u002Fcategory\u002FCBAOENLDK"},"language:1":{"id":"language:1","language":"English","__typename":"Language"},"$user:dlive-00431789.treasureChest":{"value":"2144482","state":"COLLECTING","ongoingGiveaway":null,"__typename":"TreasureChest","expireAt":"1560400949000","buffs":[],"startGiveawayValueThreshold":"500000"},"$user:dlive-00431789.videos":{"totalCount":0,"__typename":"VideoConnection"},"$user:dlive-00431789.pastBroadcasts":{"totalCount":13,"__typename":"PastBroadcastConnection"},"$user:dlive-00431789.following":{"totalCount":41,"__typename":"UserConnection"},"ROOT_QUERY":{"userByDisplayName({\"displayname\":\"thelongestchain\"})":{"type":"id","generated":false,"id":"user:dlive-00431789","typename":"User"}}}};(function(){var s;(s=document.currentScript||document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1]).parentNode.removeChild(s);}());</script>
```

I assume you'll then just have to throw in a loop and make the url dynamic to get through whatever streamers you're monitoring with your site.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I am having trouble getting curl to work (Call to undefined function curl_init()) But once I get it working I will let you know if it worked

Comment: Curl works from the console but not in the code unfortunately. phpinfo(); says it is using php7.2 and when I do php7.2 -r "curl_init();" it returns no errors. I tried installing php_curl and countless other packages but cannot get it to work. So unfortunately, this is not a possible solution atm.

Comment: Ok so I finally got curl working. Unfortunately it returns the same thing SimpleHTMLDom did, only static elements. It returns some kind of "string(23342)" though before the page content; I don't know what that is.

Comment: You also shouldn't scrape websites without their permission, but here we are.

Comment: @OverRatedProgrammer Dharman is right of course, if you can use ssl, you always should, but I was attempting to give you a block of code that will pretty much always give you what you want, in any scenario. Up to you to secure your site/how you use. But if you're only transmitting publicly available data, and the data is only read/never passed to anywhere outside this script/to determine if you display a user - then there's not much an attacker could do besides make someone appear online w/ x # of viewers on your site, even though they're offline, and if you have some very basic checks...

Comment: @OverRatedProgrammer `string(23342)` is the type and length of the content.  When you `var_dump` that information is printed first before whatever is actually in the variable.  So basically it's just saying you have a 23342 character long string of something, likely HTML.